# Chainable push()?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I would like to do:

```
arr.push('foo').filter( ... )
```

This fails because `push()` does not return the resulting array.

Is there a way to do that with pure JS or Coffee without extra libraries and without declaring a custom function?

Comment: You can't change what `push` does, if that's what you mean.

Comment: _`push()` does not return the resulting array_ ... _without declaring a custom function_. What else do you have in mind?

Comment: @Mathletics, Bergi has provided two valid options, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind not altering the array, you can use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead:

```
arr.concat('foo').filter(…)
// if you don't know whether your item is not an array, use ['foo'] instead
```

Otherwise, without a custom function, you can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
(arr.push('foo'), arr).filter(…)
```

Comment: Interesting use of `,` operator. But it doesn't look as neat when chained.

Comment: @bits: Well, for that you need custom method - however, a chainable method should not modify its arguments.

Comment: `Coffeescript` does not implement the comma operator; however a semicolon is almost as good.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

You *could* overload `Array.prototype.push` with something like this:

```
Array.prototype.push = (function(oldPush) {
     return function() {
        var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);
        oldPush.apply(this, args);
        return this;
     };
})([].push);
```

This would do the same thing as `Array.prototype.push`, and even preserve the original method, but would return the array.

**However, think before you do this.** `Array.prototype.push` is a very common function, and there's a good chance something else in your codebase will use it. You could name the new function something else, like `chainPush` or something, but extending the prototypes of built-in types like Array carries a high risk of breaking other code, especially if you're using a third-party framework.

There are all kinds of ways to make your code *look* similar, though. The easiest way is simply by using multiple, chained statements:

```
arr.push('foo'), arr.filter( ... )
```

You could even create some kind of wrapper:

```
function arrayBuilder(arr) {
   var Wrapped = function() {
       this.push = function() {
          var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);
          [].push.apply(arr, args);
          return this;
       };
       this.toArray = function() { return arr; };
   };
   return new Wrapped();
}
//usage:
var x = arrayBuilder([1,2,3]);
console.log(x.push(4).push(5).toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do that with pure JS or Coffee without extra libraries and without declaring a custom function?

I'd rethink that "no extra libraries" part. Tested and reliable code that's already written is preferable to code you have to write yourself. With that in mind, I think the safest way to do this is to use [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#_). To chain a push use the Chaining feature:

```
> arr = [12,23,34]
[12, 23, 34]
> ch = _(arr).push(48).push(56,72,78).push(92)
lodashWrapper {__chain__: ...
> ch.push(108)
lodashWrapper {__chain__: ...
> ch.value()
[12, 23, 34, 48, 56, 72, 78, 92, 48, 56, 72, 78, 92, 108]
```

If you open the console on their page you can access lodash via the `_` variable. Probably the simplest way to get a quick look at the library. If you need to push an array in you should be able to use foreach along with chaining to git er dun.

Answer (score -2):

You can overwrite the push method for the Array object:

```
Array.prototype.push = function (str) {
    this[this.length] = str;
    return this;
}
```

Or create a new method for the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.pushAndReturn = function (str) {
    this[this.length] = str;
    return this;
}

var array = [];

array.pushAndReturn('hello').pushAndReturn('world');
```

Comment: Don't do this even with different name. You should reuse `[].push()` like @justin did in his answer.